World map with country border
This code is from WMA documentation of CountryData:
Graphics[{If[CountryData[#, "AntarcticNations"], Orange, LightBrown], 
    CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"]} & /@ CountryData[]]

which produces

How to modify the code so it shows the border of every country?

Use EdgeForm, for example: Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], If[CountryData[#, "AntarcticNations"], Orange, LightBrown], CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"]} & /@ CountryData[]].
